# Adding string into innerHTML problems | select2

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2, innerhtml

Hey I have a div in my div which looks like this

```html
<div style="border-radius:2px;
           background-color:#252525;
            display:inline-block;margin-left:1.5%;
            margin-right:1.5%;margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;
            width:94%;max-width:94%;min-width:94%;
            height:100px;max-height:height:100px;
            min-height:height:100px;
            ">
            <span style="display:block;font-size:1.3em;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            ">Stats conditions</span>
            
            <div style="margin-top:1%;">
            
            
            <div style="margin-left:1.5%;
            margin-right:1.5%;display:inline-block;width: 21%;min-width: 21%;max-width:21%">
            <span style="display:block;font-size:0.8em">Gamemode</span>
            <select id="ann" class="myselect" style="display:block;width: 100%;min-width: 100%;max-width:100%">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="solo">Solo</option>
            <option value="duos">Duos</option>
            <option value="squads">Squads</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            
            <div style="margin-left:1.5%;
            margin-right:1.5%;display:inline-block;width: 21%;min-width: 21%;max-width:21%">
            <span style="display:block;font-size:0.8em">Stat type</span>
            <select id="ann" class="myselect" style="display:block;width: 100%;min-width: 100%;max-width:100%">
            <option value="kills">kills</option>
            <option value="wins">wins</option>
            <option value="kd">kd</option>
            <option value="scrim-kills">scrim kills</option>
            <option value="scrim-wins">scrim wins</option>
            <option value="scrim-kd">scrim kd</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            
             <div style="margin-left:1.5%;
            margin-right:1.5%;display:inline-block;width: 21%;min-width: 21%;max-width:21%">
            <span style="display:block;font-size:0.8em">Condition type</span>
            <select id="ann" class="myselect" style="display:block;width: 100%;min-width: 100%;max-width:100%">
            <option value="kills">Minimum</option>
            <option value="wins">Maximum</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            
            <div style="
align-tems:center;margin-left:1.5%;margin-right:1.5%;display:inline-block;width: 21%;min-width: 21%;max-width:21%">
<span style="display:block;font-size:0.8em">Enter number</span> 
<input id="everyMinutes" style="font-family:Montserrat;
display:block;width: 100%;min-width: 100%;max-width:100%;
border-radius: 3px;border: none;height: 2.35em;
"
type="number" value="">
            
            </div>
            
            
            
                           
                           
            
            </div>
            
            </div>
```

Now to add another one of these I don't add that exactly but I added it after it had been rendered by select2 so opened it and pressed f12 and copied the HTML. Now to add another one of these div's I add it to the containers HTML. Now before adding one I clicked all the select elements and it popped up fine showing my options. Now after I added one via the innerHTML method, none of the select's work anymore

edit: https://jsfiddle.net/qt0zvho3/443/
edit: To add a div to the container:
click the left div ==> view ==> add stats requirement

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this https://jsfiddle.net/5dcfmo6h/ is working as you wish.

First of all, do not use `innerHTML`, use `cloneNode` method.

Second, destroy `select2` before cloning a node. Then initialize `select2` for all `.myselect` elements again.

Third, do not use the same `id` attributes on the page again and again -- ids should be unique.

JS code:

```js
["modal1", "modal2"].forEach((modalE) => {
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalE);
  var trigger = document.getElementById(`${modalE}-t`);
  var closeButton = document.getElementById(`${modalE}-cb`);

  trigger.addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
  });
  closeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
  });
  window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }
  });
});

$(".myselect").select2({
    placeholder: "Choose a option",
});

function addStatR(){
  $(".myselect").select2('destroy');

  const clone = document.querySelector('.stats-conditions').cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('stats-conditions').appendChild(clone);

  $(".myselect").select2({
    placeholder: "Choose a option",
  });
}

const addStats = document.getElementById("addStatR")
addStats.onclick = addStatR
```

Comment: Thank you so much do you take PayPal maybe I can leave a small tip,

on top of that I only use same ID's because I am only testing, but thank you anyways